# How to redirect user to the playlist from the click of spotify button without the need to log in?

Tags: spotify

I am using Spotify Widget and the embeded code is

```
<-iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:erebore:playlist:788MOXyTfcUb1tdw4oC7KJ&view=coverart" width="292" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

There is an option for embeded code where you can show the playlist like,

```
<-iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:erebore:playlist:788MOXyTfcUb1tdw4oC7KJ" width="250" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

But due to size limitation we cannot use this code.

I would like to have the ability for users on my site to click the Spotify button on my homepage and be directed straight to playlists I have chosen.  Right now, I can only see one song at a time and if I click the Spotify icon 
it just take me to the home page of Spotify and invites me to register or log in.  Is there an easier way to direct my users straight to the music I've chosen for the theme of my website?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit unsure of how you exactly want it to look and work but you can always link to the open pages, here is an example (that will send the user to the open.spotify.com site tho):

http://open.spotify.com/user/spotify/playlist/1GQLlzxBxKTb6tJsD4RxHI

The playlist will start playing if you have the spotify desktop app open.

You can get an open link for any playlist in the Spotify client by pressing the (...) button in the header of a playlist and pick "copy http url".